# Converting If Condition to HashSet Object

Tags: java

Can any one help me how to write the below code in "if Condition" to Set object.

```
if (!(Aaa.HELLO.equals(city.getcityMethod()) || 
Aaa.BANGALORE.equals(city.getcityMethod()))
                        || !((Bbb.MYSORE.equals(city.getcityTypeInformation().getCitypurspose()))
                                || (CityPurpose.RETRIED.equals(city.getCityTypeInformation().getCitypurspose(()))
                                || (CityPurpose.SOCIAL.equals(getcityMethod.getCityTypeInformation().getCitypurspose()))
                                || (CityPurpose.COMPANY.equals(getcityMethod.getCityTypeInformation().getCitypurspose()))))
```

Some like this:

```
CONVERTING =unmodifiable::< SET>(HashSet( //here using if condition logic);
```

So that `CONVERTING` can be used like this:

```
if( CONVERTING) { // some logic}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. You want to refactor out the conditional? I mean, you're checking a bunch of different things for different conditions--what's the specific problem? You could get the city purspose (sp?) and see if it's contained in an array of the values you're checking--is that the kind of change you're looking for?

Comment: Are you asking for the Java equivalent of `getCitypurspose() IN (RETRIED, SOCIAL, COMPANY)` (assuming that `getCitypurspose()` is a typo for `getCityPurpose()`)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, put the data you want in relevant sets of the proper types, and then check these sets contain the passed data:

```
Set<CityMethod> methods=new HashSet<>();
methods.add(Aaa.HELLO);
methods.add(Aaa.BANGALORE);
Set<CityPurpose> purposes=new HashSet<>();
purposes.add(Bbb.MYSORE);
purposes.add(CityPurpose.RETRIED);
...
boolean converting=methods.contains(city.getcityMethod()) ||
                   purposes.contains(cirty.getcityTypeInformation().getcityPurpose());
if (converting) {
  ...
}
```